# how to change the design of jquery ui dialog?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I need to replace the existing jquery UI close dialog with a new close button which looks like the below link.

http://demo.tutorialzine.com/2010/12/better-confirm-box-jquery-css3/

Can anyone provide how to proceed to get a dialog like this?
what are the areas needed to change for this?

Answer (score 0):

look into jquery-ui.css for button's image and img-container. replace it with your current image location. Adjust the position a bit and you are done

Answer (score 0):

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Quincy/kHU2M/1/)**

Try to look at the source of the link you provided.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.item .delete').click(function(){
    var elem = $(this).closest('.item');
        $.confirm({
            'title'     : 'Delete Confirmation',
            'message'   : 'You are about to delete this item. <br />It cannot be restored at a later time! Continue?',
            'buttons'   : {
                'Yes'   : {
                    'class' : 'blue',
                    'action': function(){
                        elem.slideUp();
                    }
                },
                'No'    : {
                    'class' : 'gray',
                    'action': function(){}  // Nothing to do in this case. You can as well omit the action property.
                }
            }
        }); 
    });
});
```

Comment: Sorry to confuse you. I need a close button that fits to the jquery UI from outside of the alert box. You can see the rounded X button which saying "test it by clicking on the X icon". I need something like that.

Comment: So you need to tweak with the css provided.